# Rotation Detector Sequential Circuit

Tags: digital-logic, state-machines

o I have tried tackling this problem, but I cant seem to get anywhere. I dont know if I am making things too complex. I came up with this state diagram and state table. But I dont know if this is too complex. I dont even know how to implement it from my state table. I described my issue below.

[image][image]
Okay I have a system which consists of a spinning circular disk and stationary probes A (at 12 o’clock on the disk frame) and B (at 3 o’clock on the disk frame). One half of the disk is black and causes a either probe to read 1 when the black portion of the disk passes underneath it. The other half of the disk is white and causes a probe to register 0. The system has three synchronous inputs (A, B and ENABLE) and the two moore outputs (VALID and DIRECTION). I need to figure out if the disc is spinning clockwise or counterclockwise.

- When the disk is spinning at full speed ENABLE is asserted (1). While enabled, the clock frequency will be high enough to guarantee that the disk is sampled 8 times per rotation. Otherwise (when the disk is stopped or changing direction), the external system holds ENABLE low (0).
- The value of the DIRECTION should be low (0) if the direction of the spin is counterclockwise. The value of DIRECTION should be high (1) if the direction of spin is clockwise. The value of DIRECTION output is ignored (and thus can be treated as don’t care) until valid is asserted.
- Whenever ENABLE is low or when ENABLE is high and the DIRECTION is not yet valid, the output VALID is held low (0). Once the direction of the spin is determined (and the value of direction set accordingly) VALID should be asserted.
- Once the VALID is asserted, the outputs should be held stable until ENABLE goes low.

Comment: What do the optical signals look like in terms of a waveform?

Comment: What sort of technology are you trying to use to implement the system? Is it logic gates, a microcontroller, something else? Have you looked at 'quadrature encoder'? It *may* help to see how it works.

Comment: I am trying to implement this using sequential logic. AKA state devices. More particularly a Moore device. 

I dont know if my method of solving is too complex. But I am definitely stuck.

Andy- I have not yet generated any wave forms. I am just trying to get the logic behind the circuit down so I havent done any wavesforms yet. Would this help me with my design process?

Actually yes I was able to find this page here: http://www.fpga4fun.com/QuadratureDecoder.html

It helped me with some ideas. But I still dont know how to implement using my state table

Comment: The system appears to have three inputs (A, B and ENABLE), which is 8 states, but your state table seems to go upto S12. Why is that? Is this [Moore Machine wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_machine) the theory that you are using to implement?

Comment: When i was solving this problem I thought I had to have more than 8 states, is it possible to do this with only 8 states? 

I attempted doing this with 8 states but I could only figure out the begining and end states, and I did not know how to fit the rest of what I needed into the remining states

S0 = Starting state, where enable is 0
S1 = ?
S2 = ?
S3 = ?
S4 = ?
S5 = ?
S6 = 1 of 2 final states, clockwise AKA Direction = 1
S7 =  2 of 2 final states, counter clockwise AKA Direction = 0

Comment: I thought I had misunderstood, but that is okay. I'm afraid I am going out, so can't help much more. It looks like you might have a reasonable answer, though the edges on the bottom 8 states look asymmetric, which seems surprising. The machine is going to have to 'count', i.e. move through states, while it gets enough information to identify the direction. As it 'counts' it might follow two or four paths (as its states represent direction). So it doesn't seem wrong, it might be reducible, I haven't thought enough. I am assuming the direction is consistent once ENABLE becomes HIGH.

Comment: So if this is a reasonable answer how can I implement this in a logical understandable manner. Or even an easy way to implement this?